# Is it possible to use Configuration Migration Tool with Azure Devops? Dynamics 365

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dynamics-crm, devops, dynamics-365

We are using Dynamics 365 and portals (formerly known as adx portals). In the SDK is found the Migration Utility Tool, it can be used to deploy CRM data and also portal configurations between environments (source: https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/761/t/233172). But can these jobs be automated with Azure DevOps, or do I need to build my pipeline around Jenkins or something else to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to integrate the Configuration Migration Tool data imports to your Azure DevOps pipelines using the Package Deployer.

There're a few resources explaining how to create packages:

- [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/create-packages-package-deployer)
- [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJKZPu4C-O4)

In order to use the package deployer from Azure DevOps, you can use the [Dynamics 365 Build Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WaelHamze.xrm-ci-framework-build-tasks). There's a task called `MSCRM Package Deployer` which allows to easily use it from your pipelines.